# Every python module throwing error or gone missing

Tags: python-2.7

Out of nowhere I was trying to run a script I'd run hundreds of times that included the module beatbox. When I ran it I got this error:

```
import beatbox

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

I tried restarting, no luck. Then tried importing some basic libraries

```
import datetime

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

Then things started getting weirder

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _collections import deque, defaultdict
ImportError: No module named _collections
```

I have no clue what's going on, haven't done anything significant lately.

Any ideas?

Comment: what's the best process for wiping out python and reinstalling?

Comment: it depends on what OS you are running

Comment: using [brew](http://brew.sh/) is my choice for Mac

Answer (score 0):

Wow, scary stuff.

The solution to this was from wim above.

I downloaded the latest version of python and installed it. Everything is working normally now. I have no clue what happened but we're all good